# Data model design for a specialized chat application

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

I'm having difficulty designing an appropriate data model for my application.
In my application I have pairs of participants who will complete several activities together.  Each pairing will have 2-3 conversations in the course of its existence. Each conversation may have many messages that are authored by either of the participants in the pairing.
The best model I have is this:

```
         PAIRINGS
          /     \
         /       \
        V         V  
PARTICIPANTS     CONVERSATIONS
-pairing_id      -pairing_id
       \          /
        \        /
         V      V
         MESSAGES
         -participant_id
         -conversation_id
```

However this model allows for the author of a message to be outside of the pairing that is associated with the conversation and that seems wrong.  Anybody have better suggestions for how I could structure my data model?

Comment: This is just too vague. No standard notation. Not Enough detail.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post a picture so I'm unable to include a diagram.  If there are any questions I can answer I'd gladly do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem. Add the `pairing_id` in the `MESSAGES` table and change appropriately the two `FOREIGN` keys to include this column:

```
          PAIRINGS
          /     \
         /       \
        V         V  
PARTICIPANTS     CONVERSATIONS
-pairing_id      -pairing_id
       \          /
        \        /
         V      V
         MESSAGES
         -participant_id
         -conversation_id
         -pairing_id
```

Most DBMS will also require that you add `UNIQUE` indices, on `PARTICIPANTS (pairing_id, participant_id)` and on `CONVERSATIONS (pairing_id, conversation_id)`

Comment: interesting... is this a common pattern that i could read more about?  is there some term i could search for on the internet?

Comment: Yeah, I should say it's common in diamond-shaped design. See this similar question: [SQL: Normalization of database while retaining constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183039/sql-normalization-of-database-while-retaining-constraints/7183985#7183985) or this (more complex) one: [Choosing from multiple candidate keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082575/choosing-from-multiple-candidate-keys/9082972#9082972)

Comment: Beware that this requires a compound (composite) PK or Unique index and a compound Foreign Key - and that some ORMs have difficulties with compound FKs or cannot work at all with these.